# Does an op-amp's input-referred noise increase or decrease with decreasing supply voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, single-supply-op-amp

I plan to use the OP97F in an application using a single 5V supply, but all of its parameters are listed for +/-15V supply. There's a noise density graph showing it's valid from +/-2V to +/-15V but I'm not sure I trust that.

Am I right in being skeptical?

Comment: Keep in mind opamps don't know what ground is.  If it's good with a 4 V span (+/-2 V), then 5 is just fine...as long as you are driving the inputs with appropriate levels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Noise in most circuits depends on bias current in the critical components. It is easy to make bias currents quite independent of supply voltage with an internal current regulator.

There is no reason to be sceptical.

Comment: That's what I figured, I've designed CMOS op-amps and the noise is based on the biasing and construction, but I know for discrete components some datasheets provide multiple tables for max and min supply